# How to highlight all similar words in my own Editor for RCP-Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I developed an RCP-Application with RCP 3.x that contains Syntax Coloring, Formatting, AutoComplete, Error-Markers for my own Text Editor.

Now, I want to implement `Mark Occurrences`. If i click on a word in my editor, all similar words will be highlighted - similar to Java Editor.

Does anyone have an idea? 
Thanks in advance.

This is a part of my Code:

```
public class MyEditor extends TextEditor {
     String clickedWord = "";

     @Override
     protected void handleCursorPositionChanged() {
         super.handleCursorPositionChanged();

         try {
             ISourceViewer viewer = getSourceViewer();
             int caret = viewer.getTextWidget().getCaretOffset();

             clickedWord = Utils.readWordAt(viewer, caret);

             if (!clickedWord.trim().isEmpty()) {

                 Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         highlightSimilarWords();
                     }
                 });
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
     }

     private void highlightSimilarWords() {
         ISourceViewer viewer = getSourceViewer();
         IDocument document = viewer.getDocument();
         String content = document.get();

         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(clickedWord);
         Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

         while (m.find()) {
             int offset = m.start();
             int length = m.end() - m.start();

             viewer.setSelectedRange(offset, length, false);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not a code providing site. Please show us what you've tried so far and where you stuck.

Comment: The Java editor uses Annotations in the annotation model for this.

Comment: See [source code of the Java editor](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/)